# Convert CSV to JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

[image: CSV File]
Above csv file which contains nearly 2000 rows.

I want to parse CSV file line by line and convert it to JSON and send over websocket.

I found some code online which converts CSV to JSON as follows:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","IDNumber","Message")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

But the problem with above code is that we need to mention the field names to parse the CSV. Since I have more than 2000 rows, it is not a feasible solution.

Can anyone suggest how to parse CSV file line by line and convert it into JSON without specifying fieldnames?

Comment: So you want a json array, where each element in that array is a CSV line converted to json?

Comment: The fieldnames argument of DictReader is optional, if omitted the first row of the file is read to get the field names

Comment: Yes. Reading CSV line by line and convert that line to json, send it to websocket.

Comment: Beware: the so called json file will not contain valid JSON data. You will have to read it line by line and separately parse each line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Python CSV to JSON

To convert CSV to JSON in Python, follow these steps:

1. Initialize a Python List.
2. Read the lines of CSV file using `csv.DictReader()` function.
3. Convert each line into a dictionary. Add the dictionary to the Python List created in step 1.
4. Convert the Python List to JSON String using `json.dumps()`.
5. You may write the JSON String to a JSON file.

#### data.csv

- For the test I made 100.000 lines in a csv file with copy/paste, and the whole conversion takes about half a second with [Apple's M1 Chip](https://tech.ssut.me/apple-m1-chip-benchmarks-focused-on-the-real-world-programming/) while the presented example took only 0.0005 seconds.

[image]

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
value_1_1,value_1_2,value_1_3
value_2_1,value_2_2,value_2_3
value_3_1,value_3_2,value_3_3
```

#### Python Program

```py
import csv 
import json
import time

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'data.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'

start = time.perf_counter()
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Conversion 100.000 rows completed successfully in {finish - start:0.4f} seconds")
```

#### output: data.json

```sh
Conversion 100.000 rows completed successfully in 0.5169 seconds
```

```json
[
    {
        "column_1": "value_1_1",
        "column_2": "value_1_2",
        "column_3": "value_1_3"
    },
    {
        "column_1": "value_2_1",
        "column_2": "value_2_2",
        "column_3": "value_2_3"
    },
    {
        "column_1": "value_3_1",
        "column_2": "value_3_2",
        "column_3": "value_3_3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        for row in csvReader: 
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'data.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I converted a 200MB file with 600K+ rows and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the solution you have, and the only thing that bothers you is how to enter the 'long' list of column headers, i suggest you read the first (header) line of the CSV using something like reader.next(),

```
import csv

with open('your_CSV.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    field_names_list = reader.next()
```

and then split the string obtained to a list using `str.split(',')`.

The list you get can be then be fed to

```
fieldnames = (---from the above code block ---)
```

line of your code.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I dont want to write field name, Since I have got more than 2000 fields.

Comment: I understand that. That is what my solution above does. You won't have to type the field names yourself. Just get the list from the first code block above, and feed it to the variable 'fieldnames'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV has a header row : just remove the fieldnames argument from DictReader

> If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the file f will be used as the fieldnames. 
>   in https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')


reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: the problem with above procedure is that it consider the column value as string not integer or float.