# How to turn an txt file to a list with dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, txt

I'd like to know if I can turn an txt file in a list, and inside the list, a dict, just like the example

```
people = [{'name': 'Jhon', 'age':18}, {'name': 'Ian', 'age':20}, {'name': 'Annie', 'age':14}]
```

**EDIT**

The txt file looks like this:

```
Jhon, 18
Ian, 20
Annie, 14
```

Comment: Pls give us a sample txt file

Comment: How can I do this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170071/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113592/convert-csv-to-json-file-in-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
people = []
with open("./data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, age = line.split()
        people.append({"name": name, "age": int(age)})
```

or another way of doing it:

```
with open("./data.txt") as f:
    people = [
        {"name": name, "age": int(age)} for line in f for name, age in [line.split()]
    ]
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'Jhon,', 'age': 18},
 {'name': 'Ian,', 'age': 20},
 {'name': 'Annie,', 'age': 14}]
```