# Creating dictionary file using a csv file in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import csv

keys = ["id", "name", "age", "height", "weight"]
 
with open('temp.csv', 'w') as temp_file:
    dict_writer_obj = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = keys) 
    
    with open('dictReader.csv','r') as file:
        dict_reader_obj = csv.DictReader(file) 
        
        dict_writer_obj.writeheader()
        dict_writer_obj.writerows(file)
```

I want to convert a csv file called dictReader.csv file into dictionary based file:
However I am getting the following error. Any ideas?
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

My dictReader.csv file content:

```
id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

Desired output file called temp.csv with this format

```
{'id': '1', 'name': 'Alice', 'age': '20', 'height': '62', 'weight': '120.6'}
{'id': '2', 'name': 'Freddie', 'age': '21', 'height': '74', 'weight': '190.6'}
{'id': '3', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '17', 'height': '68', 'weight': '120.0'}
```

Comment: Did you mean "dictionary based file" as originally written , or perhaps a Python "dictionary object" that can be used in code?

Comment: What is what you really want to do, your code is just reading from one csv and trying to write to the other one

Comment: "_dictionary_ _based_ _file_", do you mean a JSON-file? Please show us an example of what you want the output to look like, to compliment your description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert CSV to JSON file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113592/convert-csv-to-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve on the other user's answer a bit, you can still use `writerows` like this.

```
import csv

keys = ["id", "name", "age", "height", "weight"]
 
with open('temp.csv', 'w') as temp_file:
    dict_writer_obj = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = keys) 

    with open('dictReader.csv','r') as file:
        dict_reader_obj = csv.DictReader(file) 
        dict_writer_obj.writeheader()
        # Here:
        dict_writer_obj.writerows(row for row in dict_reader_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```py
dict_writer_obj.writerows(file)
```

to:

```py
dict_writer_obj.writerows(row for row in dict_reader_obj)
```

---

Or row by row using `.writerow()`:

```py
for row in dict_reader_obj:
    dict_writer_obj.writerow(row)
```