# Dictionary to a json file using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary using the values in a csv file and values defined in the code.
Then need to write that into a json file.

The image in the below link shows the data in the csv when attached to a df.

[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyOix.png)

Below link contains the data I used in the csv file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RW9yZUWLHGXwRAxiOUchK8UkycMg2WfrX9DZwHNTjEY/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=112366564296100909730

I used the following code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')

dict = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = "aaa"
    u = "uuu"
    g = str(row['animal'])
    h = str(row['characteristic'])


    dict.update({
        "journal": [
            [f"{a}",f"{g}"],
            [f"t_s{u}",f"{h}"]
        ]})


    with open('web.json', 'a') as file:
        json.dump(dict, file)
        file.write('\n')
```

Above gave the **output** as below in 'web.json' file:

```json
{"journal": [["aaa", "dog"], ["t_suuu", "four legs"]]}
{"journal": [["aaa", "cat"], ["t_suuu", "four legs"]]}
{"journal": [["aaa", "cow"], ["t_suuu", "four egs"]]}
{"journal": [["aaa", "bird"], ["t_suuu", "two legs"]]}
{"journal": [["aaa", "ant"], ["t_suuu", "six legs"]]}
```

Comment: And what exactly do you expect? What the output should be?

Comment: You're writing in each iteration in your loop. Instead, you'll want to add to your structure (and you should call your dict something other than `dict`, because that's a keyword, or get rid of your dict entirely and just use dictreader), and not use `update` because `update` overwrites existing keys. You also don't need Pandas for this, `csv` is built in. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071962/5774952).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Post the *text* of the actual CSV, not an image of an already loaded dataframe.  Then we can copy/paste it into a CSV file for testing.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'll upload the csv. I want to update the dictionary without overwriting as below

```
{"journal": [["aaa", "dog"], ["t_suuu", "four legs"]]},
{"journal": [["aaa", "cat"], ["t_suuu", "four legs"]]},
{"journal": [["aaa", "cow"], ["t_suuu", "four egs"]]},
{"journal": [["aaa", "bird"], ["t_suuu", "two legs"]]},
{"journal": [["aaa", "ant"], ["t_suuu", "six legs"]]}
```

Comment: never use the keyword `dict` for a variable name as you're currently overshadowing the actual keyword

Comment: Hi @Mark Tolonen,
I've updated the main text with the link to my csv data.

Comment: Hi J_H,
Sure, will not do that again.

Comment: Hi Zac Anger,
Thank you. I'll try as mentioned and refer the link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dict` to record data and saving to JSON file on every loop, use `List` and append the object to the list on each loop. After loop exits, dump that list of data (array of objects) to JSON file.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')

dict = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = "aaa"
    u = "uuu"
    g = str(row['animal'])
    h = str(row['characteristic'])


    dict.append({
        "journal": [
            [f"{a}",f"{g}"],
            [f"t_s{u}",f"{h}"]
        ]})


with open('web.json', 'a') as file:
    json.dump(dict, file)

# Later you can delete `dict` (containing objects array) variable from memory
# del dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')

final_data = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dict = {}
    for key,value in zip(row.index, row.values):
        dict[key] = value

    final_data.append(dict)


with open('web.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(final_data, file)
```

As @pratik-ghodke mentioned you should be using a `List` instead of `dict` to store the data and then dump the `List` to the json file.

The code above will store the data to web.json file in the following format

```
[{"animal": "dog", "characteristic": "four legs", "groups": "mammal"}, {"animal": "cat", "characteristic": "four legs", "groups": "mammal"}]
```