# Add an index or id value to JSON

Tags: python, json

I've got a JSON file similar to this:

```
{
    "Name": "a1",
    "Notes": "b1",
    "Active": "c1"
},
{
    "Name": "a2",
    "Notes": "b2",
    "Active": "c2"
},
{
    "Name": "a3",
    "Notes": "b4",
    "Active": "c3"
}
```

I need to transform it using Python by adding a progressive "index"/"id" for every data block.
This is the desired output (notice that there are no quotes around the "id" value):

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "Name": "a1",
    "Notes": "b1",
    "Active": "c1"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "a2",
    "Notes": "b2",
    "Active": "c2"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "a3",
    "Notes": "b4",
    "Active": "c3"
}
```

If it might be useful I'm building this JSON by converting a CSV using the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071962/4712710

Comment: This JSON needs square brackets `[]`. I imagine you just missed them while copy the file, since the guide you're using should include them. Please [edit] to fix that.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Like, are you aware of the `enumerate` function? Do you know how to read JSON data, modify it, and write it back? You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can add new keys to each dictionary using `enumerate()`:

```py
import json

original_json_text = """[
    {"Name": "a1", "Notes": "b1", "Active": "c1"},
    {"Name": "a2", "Notes": "b2", "Active": "c2"},
    {"Name": "a3", "Notes": "b4", "Active": "c3"}
]"""

data = json.loads(original_json_text)

data = [{"id": i, **d} for i, d in enumerate(data)]

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "Name": "a1",
        "Notes": "b1",
        "Active": "c1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "a2",
        "Notes": "b2",
        "Active": "c2"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Name": "a3",
        "Notes": "b4",
        "Active": "c3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
I was totally unaware that I could use enumerate there, I've got something more to study.

Thanks a lot, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly simply with the JSON library.

```py
import json

json_array = json.loads('''
    [
        {
            "Name": "a1",
            "Notes": "b1",
            "Active": "c1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "a2",
            "Notes": "b2",
            "Active": "c2"
        },
        {
            "Name": "a3",
            "Notes": "b4",
            "Active": "c3"
        }
    ]
''')

for i, d in enumerate(json_array):
    d["id"] = i

print(json.dumps(json_array))
```

This parses the json code into a python object, and then iterates through the array and adds the id field.

Comment: Beside the point, but `object` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `object` type](//docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object). It'd be better to use a more descriptive name like maybe `json_object`, or something like `d` for "dict".

Comment: Also, the wording could be more precise: *"This interprets the json code as a python object, and then iterates through the array"* -- I'd say "This **parses** the json code **into** a python object, and then iterates through the **list**".

Comment: Excellent suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Full example, with some comments:

```
import json

# with open is important to close the file regardless of result 
with open('my_file.json') as f:
    # here we read the file and use json module to unpack
    content = json.loads(f.read())

# list comprehension, merge 2 dictionaries and enumerate, you can read more about those)
content = [{"id": index, **obj} for index, obj in enumerate(content)]
```